# How do i load data to Datatable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

i have the following `ajax` call to call action method to get a list of products based on their product Category.

`'#ddlProductCategoriesList'` is a drop down list (Product Category), when the selection changes it should fetch products in that category and assign them to a `JQuery` `Datatable`. I was able to destroy the previous data in the jquery table but after destroying it could not initialize it with new data, How do i load jquery `datatable` with new data?

Note: The Action returned data as json successfully but load data to table failed

```
    $('#ddlProductCategoriesList').change(function (item) {

        var x = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProductsByCategory","Products")',
            method: 'get',
            cache:false,
            data: { 'cid': x },
            contentType: 'application/json; chatset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                      
                alert('hello');

                table.destroy();

                $('#t1').empty();

                $('#t1').dataTable({
                    data: data,
                    columns: [
                        { 'data': 'item.ID' },
                        { 'data': 'item.CategoryID' },
                        { 'data': 'item.ProductName' },
                        { 'data': 'item.LastName' }

                    ]
                });


            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
                alert("error")

            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What is `table` in `table.destroy()`? I assume its `var table = $('#t1').DataTable();`? Also you can remove `contentType: 'application/json; chatset=utf-8',` - its pointless for a GET (and if it was a POSTit would not work anyway because you have not stringified the data)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  table is var table = $('#t1').DataTable();

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke it says table.destroy() is not a function

Comment: Can you try `$('#t1').DataTable().destroy();` instead (do you get the same error?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke this time it worked! : ) why it doesnt like calling destroy() from 'table'?

Comment: You have not shown where your declared the `var table = $('#t1').DataTable();` so best guess is that it was not global (i.e. you put it inside another function)

Comment: Why don't you use Datatables build-in functions for filtering which also support data reloading via Ajax ?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use Datatables built-in support for filtering?

Here is a reduced example of how it can be implemented

Datatables markup:

```
<table class="table" id="dt">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="filter">
            <td>
                <select id="dropDownWithCategories">
                    <option value="1">Category 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Category 2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="filter-submit">Search</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Product</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Datatables initialization:

```
grid.init({  // grid.init calls an own datatables wrapper class which I will ignore...
    src: $("#dt"),
    dataTable: {
        ajax: {
            url: "/Products/GetProductsByCategory", // 
            data: function (d) {
                d.id = $("#dropDownWithCategories").val(); // Here you add the category parameter when calling GetProducts
            }
        },
        serverSide: true,
        filter: true,
        retrieve: true,
        columns: [
        { data: "Id" },
        { data: "Product" }
        ]
    }
});
```

This way you forget about reloading the table manually. There is plenty of information available in the official documentation with lots of examples

https://www.datatables.net